# AWS ElasticSearch shrink API node name

Tags: aws-elasticsearch

AWS Docs for AWS ElasticSearch have a section about the shrink API:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_api_notes-shrink

The sample shows how to shrink:

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": "name-of-the-node-to-shrink-to",
    "index.blocks.read_only": true
  }
}
```

```json
PUT https://domain.region.es.amazonaws.com/source-index/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": null,
    "index.blocks.read_only": false
  }
}

PUT https://domain.region.es.amazonaws.com/shrunken-index/_settings
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": null,
    "index.blocks.read_only": false
  }
}
```

Where do I get the `name-of-the-node-to-shrink-to`, `source-index` and `shrunken-index`?

Answer (score 2):

For shrink operation:

> All primary shards for the index must reside on the same node.
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-shrink-index.html

"**name-of-the-node-to-shrink-to**" parameter relocates the index’s shards to this particular node.

You can get the nodes name for your cluster using the [cat nodes API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html):

```
GET /_cat/nodes?v&h=name
```

Next, your **source-index** in the index that you want to perform shrink operation on. This process creates a new target index which will be your **shrunken-index**

You will make the following API call to perform the shrink operation:

```
POST /my_source_index/_shrink/my_target_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index.routing.allocation.require._name": null, 
    "index.blocks.write": null 
  }
}
```

The other two calls that you see in the AWS documentation are for clearing the allocation requirement for the **source-index** and **shrunken-index**

You can also follow [Elastic's guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-shrink-index.html) on the same.